# paramiko sftp - when trying to download a file, I get OSError File path illegal

Tags: python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

Initializing paramiko sftp client:

```
t = paramiko.Transport((self.sftp_server, 7790)) 
t.connect(None,self.sftp_user, self.sftp_pw)  
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
```

listing the files:

```
dirlist = sftp.listdir(".")

print("Dirlist: %s" % dirlist)

files = sftp.listdir(path=self.location)

print(files)
```

gives all the files correctly.

but when reading a file form the list

```
 with sftp.open('/VA_EBAC_UP/EBAC_Article_KPI_Report.txt', "r") as f:
                data = f.read()
```

I get an error:

> Caught exception: : File path
>   [EBAC_Article_KPI_Report.txt]  illegal.

full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_sftp_file_yohan.py", line 234, in get_ftp_files
    with sftp.open('/VA_EBAC_UP/EBAC_Article_KPI_Report.txt', "r") as f:
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 372, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 813, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 865, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 898, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)
OSError: File path [EBAC_Article_KPI_Report.txt]  illegal.
```

Comment: What is `VA_EBAC_UP`? How does it relate to `self.location`? + What SFTP server is that? + Can you download the file using any SFTP client - Like WinSCP? Can you post its verbose log file?

Comment: VA_EBAC_UP is just a folder inside the MFT server (this is a linux location). I am able to download from this location using an SFTP client like Core FTP. I will post the verbose log file in sometime.

Comment: well looks like I was able to solve this - the FTP server did not give permission for download - only for upload.

Answer (score 0):

this was a Permissions issue. The SFTP server only allowed uploads and I was trying to download from the same server. Maybe this will help someone else - but wish that the error message was verbose enough to highlight permission issue.

```
**d-wx------**   1 0        0            4096 05 Nov 00:00 VA_EBAC_UP
```

reading any file from the above folder gives:
Caught exception: : File path []  illegal.